PHP Laravel SQLSTATE[HY000]
I have a problem... ORM
When I use
php artisan tinker,
use App\\Models\\User

    $u = new User();

 $u->title = 'sale';

    $u->content = 'auto ...';

    $u->price = 2500;

HERE ARE GOOD EVERYTHING, BUT...
when I type command
$u->save();

I see

Illuminate\Database\QueryException  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: users (SQL: insert into "users" ("title", "content", "price", "updated_at", "created_at") values (sale, auto ..., 2500, 2024-10-30 14:31:15, 2024-10-30 14:31:15)).

What can it be? All migrations is good, I have a table sqlite.
I have done everything from book, just change names of models etc
Laraver 9, PHP 8.3, Ubuntu, local
I check it app DB Browser for SQLite.

did you run your migrations using php artisan migrate ? Does your table exist?

Do you have a users table in your sqlite database?

Make sure the setup is what you think it is. It might be that you are using an in memory db.

here are some reasons

make sure the table is in the db, browse the tables in your DB
the table name might not meet the Laravel approach (name not users)
set the table name inside the model

protected $table = 'users'; // or whatever the table name

so check your DB tale and provide a screen and more details if not a case

The error suggest that the users table doesn't exist in your database
